# Is there a contraction for non-exclusive or?

Tags: terminology, contractions, logic

I find that often, in technical writing, I want to specify that or is non-exclusive: or ≠ xor; or = and/or.

*(Stylistically, "and or" is terrible and gets tiresome quickly;)*

As an example of the type of ambiguity that can arise, see [I need clarification on the use of the word “either”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/410422/216884).

If one has established an "xor" in natural language, "or" can be assumed to be non-exclusive can be assumed, but that may not be explicit enough.

- Has attempted to introduce, even unsuccessfully, a contraction for "non-exclusive or" that relates symbolically to xor?

### --------------------------------------------

Russel & Whitehead used "v" as a symbol.  [See: [Symbol for 'Or']](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/345857/216884)

See also: [Does “or” mean both conditions?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/101717/216884)

Comment: I hope this question will be found tolerable, as it is a serious one.  I linked three related, useful (but under-voted) previous stack questions.

Comment: There's only *and/or* really. It does get tiresome, but the workarounds are not much less tiresome, and in any long-ish piece of writing (in a field where this comes up a lot), you will eventually come across a situation where even the best workaround is so clumsy it's better to use *and/or* - and then you'll wish you'd bitten the bullet the first time and used it throughout.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no natural language contraction for the ***inclusive*** *or*.

In fact, in order to make it explicit, you have to write something even longer:

> You can choose A, B, or A and B.

But even that may not be explicit enough—because it doesn't absolutely rule out the possibility of *not* making a choice—or making a choice that *isn't* any of those things.

If an *inclusive* choice has be made, then you have to say something like this:

> You *must* choose A, B, or A and B.

---

Note that this also applies to the natural language equivalent of the ***exclusive*** *or*:

> You can choose either A or B, but not both.

Generally, adding just *either* is enough; however, many people add the extra three words if they want to make sure there is no room for any confusion at all.

And also, in the more explicit version:

> You *must* choose either A or B, but not both.